# LeetCode Problem 895 (Python), can't finish last test

Tags: python

[Link to problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-frequency-stack/)
I've been trying to solve this problem and have come very close. I'm looking to fix the push method, but for the last call:

```
freq_stack = [5, 7, 4]
freq_stack.pop()
```

It returns [5, 4], not [5, 7]

Here is my code:

```
class FreqStack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def push(self, val: int) -> None:
        self.stack.append(val)

    def pop(self) -> int:
        mock_stack = self.stack[:]
        unique_nums = []

        while True:
            if len(mock_stack) != 1:
                for num in mock_stack:
                    if num not in unique_nums:
                        mock_stack.remove(num)
                        unique_nums.append(num)

                unique_nums.clear()

            else: break

        most_freq_num = mock_stack[0]         

        reversed_stack = self.stack[::-1]

        reversed_stack.remove(most_freq_num)

        self.stack = reversed_stack[::-1]    # After removing most freqent item, update stack.

        return most_freq_num
```

Comment: If you want, you can find the solution with python code here: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-frequency-stack/solution/

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see how code works.

Comment: Hi, rather than recalculate some of this stuff, can you think about just keeping track of it?

Comment: here is another possible solution I found online https://leetcode.ca/2018-05-13-895-Maximum-Frequency-Stack/#solution